# Differential signal processing and generation

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, operational-amplifier, signal, differential

I am trying to interface to a Mitsubishi central aircon unit. Based upon the manual, the internal units communicate over a differential bus (I hope is TDM).

I have a screenshot of the signal:

[image]

How would I go interfacing to this bus? I realize this requires an opamp in differential mode, but I am unable to find implementation details, besides theory. The idea is to use an opamp to subtract the signal, and have the single-ended output drive a high impedance input of a microcontroller (probably atmega238).

After receiving and decoding, and assuming I understand how the bus is multiplexed (or shared), how would I be able to generate a differential signal?

Even the correct terminology will help.

Comment: Do you know the amplitude of the signal? Can you see either in the physical unit or in the service manual what component is generating these signals?

Comment: My first guess would be that they use something like RS-485. There are lots of *RS-485 transceiver* chips available. But there are other possibilities.

Comment: The amplitude is 5v. All I care about is reading the bits, before I decode manually by sampling it. Since the bus has no common/ground connector, I need to extract the signal, which is the purpose of the question. My belief is that the signalling is proprietary, although some flavor of rs485 is likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is almost certainly an RS485 signal. It's a very robust differential protocol used a lot in industrial settings.

RS485 is just a signalling standard, there is no protocol. Typically standard UART protocols are used. Because of this a standard PC RS232 connection, through an RS232 to RS485 level converter is all that's needed to connect to the device.

I recommend purchasing something like this: [http://www.amazon.com/RS232-To-RS485-Converter-Adapter/dp/B003MN1KKQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MN1KKQ) and testing the output to confirm that it is giving you UART type signaling.

You should be able to bring the RS232 level signal into a PC and view the result in a terminal. I love realterm for this, because it has a good "hex mode" which helps you confirm that there is real data there, even if the protocol is binary and not ASCII text.

If all goes well, and you can confirm that you are dealing with RS485 there are plenty of RS485 to LVTTL level chips that will interface cleanly to your microcontroller pins.

If you really need to use an opamp for this, a standard subtractive circuit will do the trick:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flGucM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a possibility of using an op-amp to convert to rs232 levels? While I have rs232-ttl level shifters, I have none for rs485.

Comment: It in fact, works almost perfectly. The only problem is it seems to be idle low, shouldn't it be idle high? My decoder generates framing errors.

Comment: Also, I don't want to make a big deal out of it, but how would I go _transmitting_ on the bus?

Comment: You seem to know what the bus looks like when active and when it it idle. If you could edit your diagram to highlight both sections, then we could help you out. If you think you just need a polarity inversion of the output, you can swap the + and - input terminals.